# How to move an existing wordpress azure web app code to visual studio team support git repo?

Tags: wordpress, azure, azure-devops

I am running a WordPress website on Windows Azure platform for 8 months now. How can i implement version control? I want to move the source code of my website to VSTS git repository so that i can keep track of all the changes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the code to VS-team-Services manually.

If the source code just in Azure web app:

1. Go to https://[sitename].scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole
2. Click site folder
3. Click Download icon of wwwroot to download the source code

If there is the source code in local, you can add it to VSTS git repository through Visual Studio or Git tool.

1. Create a new git repository in your VSTS.
2. Open Team explorer window in VS
3. Click manage connections
4. Click New in Local Git Repositories> Specify path
5. Double click this repository to connect to it
6. Click Settings> Repository Settings
7. Click Add in Remotes section> Specify your VSTS repository URL>Save
8. Copy source files to this repository
9. Click Home icon in Team explorer >Changes
10. Commit changes
11. Go to Home> Sync >Push

After that you can [continuous deployment to azure app service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-continuous-deployment). You also could to do it through VSTS build and release. [Implement continuous deployment of your app to an Azure App Services website](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/apps/cd/deploy-webdeploy-webapps)